# Custom ScrollBar Implementation for GWT [SmartGWT]

Tags: gwt, scroll, smartgwt

I am trying to make a custom scrollbar for my gwt project, same as the one in the attached picture. It behaves like when the container overflow horizontally, an icon with the arrow will be shown on the right side, instead of showing the horizontal scroll bar, and on clicking on this arrow, it will act the same way as the scrollbar would.

I tired to search for similar components, but got no result [may be i am not searching for it with the right key words :( ]

Could any one help me in building/finding such a component using GWT/SmartGWT

[Scroll Bar marked in red on right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgSrM.png)

Comment: Did you search on SmartGWT showcase?

Comment: Yes, I didn't find any component like this in there

Comment: If i were you I would consider writing my own button to handle the scrolling function, because I've never seen scroll like this in SmartGWT/GWT components.

Comment: Hi Hubert, I am trying to implement the same you suggested, but i am not able to figure out how to identify when to show and when not to show the button and the way to control the scroll, can you please guide me with that

Comment: Maybe some window resolution checking + counting overall components width will do. ;)

Comment: seems like there is not straightforward way to identify if the component is overflowing or not :(